# Convert excel column letter to integer in Ruby

Tags: ruby, excel

What's are the simplest way to convert excel-like column letter to integer?

for example:

```
AB --> 27
AA --> 26
A --> 0
Z --> 25
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
def excel_col_index( str )
  value = Hash[ ('A'..'Z').map.with_index.to_a ]
  str.chars.inject(0){ |x,c| x*26 + value[c] + 1 } - 1
end
```

Or

```
def excel_col_index( str )
  offset = 'A'.ord - 1
  str.chars.inject(0){ |x,c| x*26 + c.ord - offset } - 1
end
```

Comment: i think the second one is beautiful :3

Comment: Both of these need to have a 1 subtracted from the answer to be correct. They return 1 for "A" and 27 for "AA".

Comment: This won't work for lowercase letters, (`excel_col_index('b') #=> 34`). If you need that change it to ...`str.upcase.chars.inject`...

Comment: @Br.Bill good spot - I've edited the answer to have the - 1 needed and added a spec as a separate answer below.

Answer (score 5):

I would do something like this:

```
def column_name_to_number(column_name)
  multipliers = ('A'..'Z').to_a
  chars = column_name.split('')

  chars.inject(-1) { |n, c| multipliers.index(c) + (n + 1) * 26 }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

here's a version of the accepted answer, with a spec:

```rb
RSpec.describe "#excel_col_index" do
  def excel_col_index(str)
    value = Hash[('A'..'Z').map.with_index.to_a]
    str.chars.inject(0) { |x, c| x * 26 + value[c] + 1 } - 1
  end

  { "A" => 0, "Z" => 25, "AB" => 27, "AA" => 26 }.each do |col, index|
    it "generates #{index} from #{col}" do
      expect(excel_col_index(col)).to eq(index)
    end
  end
end
```

(but I'll also edit the accepted answer to have the required `- 1`)

Answer (score 2):

ah nevermind..

```
def cell2num col
  val = 0
  while col.length > 0
    val *= 26
    val += (col[0].ord - 'A'.ord + 1)
    col = col[1..-1]
  end
  return val - 1
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those bits that you can keep iterating on for a long time. I ended up with this:

```rb
"AB1".each_codepoint.reduce(0) do |sum, n|
  break sum - 1 if n < 'A'.ord  # reached a number
  sum * 26 + (n - 'A'.ord + 1)
end # => 27
```

From the [xsv](https://github.com/martijn/xsv) source code